# copy every nth file and retain directory structure

Tags: powershell

I need to copy every nth file from a folder (including subfolders) to another location but maintain folder structure.

I have found a few snippets but none quite fit my requirements, either they copy random files to one folder or copy all files but maintain folder structure. The closest I have come is this.

```
$Source = "C:\source"
$Destination = "C:\destination"
$Skip = 10

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $Source -File | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName }

for( $idx = 0; $idx -lt $Files.count; $idx += $Skip ) {
$Files[$idx] | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -container -recurse
}
```

I feel like I am on the right path as I get every nth file, however in the destination folder all files are in the root and directory structure is lost. I think his maybe due to the every nth `for` loop not working with `Copy-Item` and stripping the path?

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop to:

```
for( $idx = 0; $idx -lt $Files.count; $idx += $Skip ) {
    Copy-Item -Path $Files[$idx] -Destination ($Files[$idx]).Replace($Source,$Destination) -Force
}
```

This uses the full path, substituting the `$Source` part with `$Destination`.

The `-Force` parameter means any parent folders will be created if need be.

Not sure if the `-Recurse` and `-Container` parameters are required for your task - add them back if need be.

Comment: Tried the change but the script fails with the following (I should add that it did copy files from the root folder though).....

Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\copydest\2\files.txt'.
At line:9 char:5
+     Copy-Item -Path $Files[$idx] -Destination ($Files[$idx]).Replace( ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: @Dont-Fight-The-Future That's what I'd expect if the `-Force` parameter wasn't included...